# visualizar videos y fotos en un mismo picturebox de visual studio que estan en una carpeta

Tags: visual-studio

Es posible visualizar en visual basic, en un control picturebox imagenes y videos a la vez de forma transitoria? tengo el conocimiento de como hacerlo pero por separado, no se como hacer que pasen tanto fotos como videos de forma automatica unos entre otros, contenidos en la misma carpeta..

asi lo hago con imagenes:

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.1.251;Initial Catalog=infomuni;User ID=sa; Password=2005;"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ubicacion FROM fotos"
    Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If lrd.Read() Then
        lblSlideRuta.Text = lrd("ubicacion")
    End If
    con.Close()

    If lblSlideRuta.Text <> "" Then

        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(lblSlideRuta.Text)
        ImageDir = di.GetFiles("*.jpg").Concat(di.GetFiles("*.bmp")).Concat(di.GetFiles("*.png")).Concat(di.GetFiles("*.gif")).ToArray
        Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
        frm = New Form
        frm.Name = "frm"
        FullSizePic = New PictureBox
        FullSizePic.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        FullSizePic.BackColor = Color.Black
        FullSizePic.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom

        PicBoxImagenes.Controls.Add(FullSizePic)
        AddHandler frm.KeyDown, AddressOf frm_keydown

        TimerSlide.Enabled = True

        GetnextImage()
    End If
```